# adding polynomials using an array of terms

Tags: arrays

I am trying to create a program that can add two polynomials that are stored in an array. Each term of a polynomial(coefficient and exponent) is stored as one index in an array(I have a term class that does this). When I call my add method, it's not always combining coefficients that have the same exponents.

My last condition adds the 2 coefficients if the exponents are alike. How would I create a loop that goes through my Polynomial after a Term has already be assigned? Maybe there's a more efficient way to go about this.

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int newin = 0; //index or location of new terms being stored for Polynomial p3
    Polynomial p3 = new Polynomial();


    while (i<p1.TermLength || j<p2.TermLength)
    {


           if (i==p1.TermLength)
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p2.poly[j].getExpo());
                j++;    // j is increased whenever a term from Poly2 has been utilized
           }

         else if (j==p2.TermLength)
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
                i++;    // i is increased by 1 whenever a term from Poly1 has been utilized
           }

         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo()>p2.poly[j].getExpo())
            {
               p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
                i++;
            }

         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo()<p2.poly[j].getExpo())
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p2.poly[j].getExpo());
                j++;
            }                             
         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo() == p2.poly[j].getExpo())
         {
            p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
            p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff() + p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
            i++;
            j++;
         }  

         newin++;


    }


    p3.TermLength = p3.poly.length;

    return p3;
}
```

Comment: I think the first two `if-else` should be separate and the last three `if-else` should be separate as the condition are totally different in those two blocks

Comment: I don't think that helps it?

Comment: Yes ...
Can you please give an example of what answer you expect and what answer you are getting instead.

Comment: Also provide the arrangement of order of polynomials...
is it `X^2+2X+1` or is it `1+2X+X^2` or is it unsorted...This will make the question easy for understanding also Suppose end of polynomial `p1` is reached then polynomial `p2` will not be appended by your code